# Securely Forward Service on Private Network to Client on Another Private Network

Tags: ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, remote-desktop, spice

I have two computers on private networks and a VPS, all running Linux. I would like to be able to make a secure tunnel between the two computers so that one can securely access services hosted by the other.

I have tried looking at other solutions, but as far as I can tell they do not create a 'seamless' and secure tunnel between the two computers because one has to ssh into a VPS then ssh into the second computer from there after reverse forwarding it to the VPS, or they only work for SSH and don't allow forwarding other applications. This doesn't allow me to access the interface directly from the first computer as far as I know.

Let us call these the Remote Computer, VPS, and Local Computer.

- Remote Computer: Hosts Services (Spice Server)
- VPS: Forwards Services
- Local Computer: Accesses Services

```
 ________________       _____       _________________
|                |     |     |     |                 |
| Local Computer | <-> | VPS | <-> | Remote Computer |
|________________|     |_____|     |_________________|

(<-> = Secure SSH Tunnel)
```

I tried using SSH, but could not figure out how to do it securely. One of the services I am trying to forward is a Spice server and I did so by setting `GatewayPorts` to yes in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the VPS and running the command `ssh -R 55667:localhost:5900 user@VPS_IP` on the Remote Computer, which allowed me to access the spice server by running `remote-viewer spice://VPS_IP:55667` on the Local Computer. That, of course, wasn't be very secure though.

A second solution I am considering is to use the following commands to try to make a secure connection:

```
# Remote Computer
ssh -R 55667:localhost:5900 user@VPS_IP

# Local Computer
ssh -L 55667:localhost:55667 user@VPS_IP
remote-viewer spice://localhost:55667
```

For this `GatewayPorts` was enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I should also note that the spice server allows for one to set a password, though I'm pretty sure it doesn't encrypt anything and I am unsure about it's ability to protect the VM against attackers. This solution works, or at least I was able to access the spice server using the last command, but it still leaves the server accessible for people to do things like attempt to brute force the password for the spice server.

Will the last example create a secure connection between the Local Computer and remote Computer? If not, is there a simple way to make a secure tunnel using something like SSH between the two computers so that I could, for example, run `remote-viewer spice://localhost:55667` on the Local Computer, to access the spice server on the Remote Computer?

Thank you in advance, and please let me know if there is any other information about the question I should provide!

Comment: This, to me, sounds like what you really want is either a) a classical VPN, where local and remote connect to VPS on a private IP, or b) a slightly quicker/less overhead variant, setting up wireguard in a hub-and-spoke configuration.

Comment: @tink, thank you! That is what I was really looking for, I just didn't know it. After playing around with it for a day I got it working with wireguard. The only issue I have now is that the 'spokes' disconnect from the virtual network and won't reconnect unless I ping another spoke, meaning SSH doesn't really work, hopefully I'll figure that part out soon enough.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear that, good luck w/ the timeouts! :)

Comment: Btw, wireguard is stateless, so if ssh is your primary use-case and your ssh-sessions keep timing out you may want to use an ssh-setting to alleviate that.  Edit `~/.ssh/config` and add these two statements near the top: `ServerAliveInterval 30
     ServerAliveCountMax 3`

Comment: @tink, thanks a lot! I fixed the timeouts by adding the `PersistentKeepAlive` option to all the spokes.

Comment: I'll try your suggestions for the ssh configs. I'm having trouble with wireguard being blocked in places like the Library, but can still access services with `ssh -L`. The config options you mentioned might keep the ssh tunnel open in those situations if I can't find a better solution.

Comment: If firewalling gets in the way (and the firewalls aren't doing deep packet inspection) you could go with OpenVPN after all. It allows you to use TCP (a tad slower) on arbitrary ports; using 443 lets you bypass many a naughty firewall ;) ... we had people "calling home" from a heavily firewalled country uninhibited ;)